# Edit/update tags in activeadmin when using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, tags, activeadmin

I am using Rails4 and Ruby2.0

I have a model (say blog_post_ for which I am using acts_as_taggable (gem). I am also using the activeadmin gem to easily edit/delete some records in production.

For the blog_post model I can see all its attributes [ex : title, author etc] in the active admin edit page, however I don't see the tags associated with the post (eg tags for a post are: tech, business, food etc)

How can I view and edit the tags from a given posts page :

```
eg from this page http://localhost:3000/admin/posts/37/edit
```

I want to be able to edit/add the tags on that post.

Comment: Your question is not clear , what do you mean by 'I can see all its attributed in the active admin edit page, however I dont see its associated tags.' ?

Comment: I made some edit. Thanks for pointing out. Let me know if its still not clear

Comment: sorry mate ..i got your question but i am not active admin expert, may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184718/1970061

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize your show and new/edit pages:

```
# for new/edit pages
form do |f|
  # existing content
  f.input :tag_list # this will display the tag list column
end

# for show pages
show do
  # existing content
  row :tag_list
end
```

Relevant sections from ActiveAdmin documentation:

- http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html
- http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html